# How to use Colorbox with Shopify Pages?

Tags: jquery, shopify, lightbox, colorbox

I'm pretty new to all of this but I'm helping a nonprofit customize their Shopify sites. Currently, we are trying to have the pages in the navigation bar in the header open into lightboxes as opposed to opening a new page. 
I have added these colorbox files to my Assets folder:

```
jquery.colorbox-min.js
jquery.colorbox.js
colorbox.css
```

and added this to my theme's header:

```
 {{ 'colorbox.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
 {{ 'jquery.colorbox.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
 {{ 'jquery.colorbox-min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }}
```

I assume the actual code to create the lightbox will be within the header.liquid since that is where the links to the pages are opened from but everything I have found online regarding colorbox hasn't worked. This was what I added based on viewing the source from colorbox's examples page:

```
$(function ()
{
    $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});    
})


<a class="iframe" href="{{ link.url }}">
{{ link.title }}
```

I also just tried it with a simple Wikipedia link and the lightbox isn't working at all.